# Клик по составному элементу внутри сложного Item'а ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Имеется `ListView`, сложные `Item`'ы которого содержат три `TextView` и один `ImageView`.

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы нажимать можно было на отдельный составной `TextView` (а не на весь `Item`)?

Буду благодарен за любую информацию на эту тему.

Comment: ближе к ответу я не стал ...

Comment: Что у Вас является **одним** элементом `ListView`? Что этот элемент в себе содержит?

Comment: путь в тысячу миль начинается с одной

Comment: это элемент TexvView по нажатию на который откроется диалоговое окно

Comment: он есть во всех списках

Comment: Если этот ответ мне, то спрошу: а причем тут тогда «3 текста и 1 фото»?

Comment: да ответ вам,при том что каждый список list view содержит это а мне надо сделать кликабельным всего 1 из этих итемов,добавил itemonclik

Comment: нажимается весь пункт

Comment: так можно?textView.setOnClickListener

Comment: Не знаю. Я так толком и не понял вопроса.

Comment: А что насчет RecyclerView ?

Comment: а как это hеализовать ,можно по подробнее?пример

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял  вашу задачу:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rootView = convertView;

    rootView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_item_list, parent, false);

    tvFirst = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirst);
    tvSecond = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSecond);
    tvSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Так у вас только при нажатии на конкретную `view` будет что то выполнятьсяю

Comment: Спасибо наиболее точный отет то что мне надо)